# React - How to find out the last document in a FireStore collection

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

The following component connects to a Cloud FireStore collection when it's mounted and shows only one document .limit(1).

Each time the user clicks the **Next** button a new request is sent to FireStore and shows the next document form the collection.

It's working fine. There's only one issue:

When the user clicks the Next button several times and reaches the last document inside the FireStore collection, the next click breaks the code, which makes sense.

I want that when the last document is reached, the next click on the **Next** button shows the first document or at least a message that the last item is reached.

How can I do this? How can I find out the last document in a FireStore collection?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { db } from '../firebase';

const FlipCard = () => {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const data = await db
        .collection('FlashCards')
        .orderBy('customId', 'asc')
        .limit(1)
        .get();
      setCards(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const showNext = ({ card }) => {
    const fetchNextData = async () => {
      const data = await db
        .collection('FlashCards')
        .orderBy('customId', 'asc')
        .limit(1)
        .startAfter(card.customId)
        .get();
      setCards(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
    };

    fetchNextData();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {cards.map((card) => (
            <div className='card__face card__face--front'>
              {<img src={card.imgURL} alt='' />}
              {card.originalText}
            </div>
            <div className='card__face card__face--back'>
              {card.translatedText}
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() => showNext({ card: cards[cards.length - 1] })}
        >
          Next Card
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default FlipCard;
```

Answer (score 2):

The way to know that you're out of docs in a collection is when the number of results (`cards.length`) is smaller than the limit on the query (`.limit(1)`).

The code is breaking because it doesn't anticipate that condition:

```
onClick={() => showNext({ card: cards[cards.length - 1] })}
                                      ^ this expression might be -1
```

One way to fix is to conditionally render the button only if `cards.length > 0`.

Another way is to conditionally compute the parameter to showNext...

```
{ card: cards.length > 0 ? cards[cards.length - 1] : {} }
```

...and handle that case in the method.

Answer (score 1):

just handle an error

```
const showNext = ({ card }) => {
    const fetchNextData = async () => {
      const data = await db
        .collection('FlashCards')
        .orderBy('customId', 'asc')
        .limit(1)
        .startAfter(card.customId)
        .get()
        .catch(error => {  console.log('end of the row') });

        if(!data.docs.length) console.log('end of the row');

      setCards(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
    };

    fetchNextData();
  };
```

Comment: It looks the OP's failure happens before the call to showNext, while computing the card parameter to that call.

Comment: Not really. Every time user hits next - card that follows (startAfter) last loaded card (cards.length -1) is pulled from database. Now at that point ‘code breaks’, and being that we were not specified if it throws a firebase error or returns an empty docs object - we want to handle both or ether one that works.

Comment: Consider the case when there are no more cards.  This answer suggests calling `setCards` with an empty array.  That works fine.  (Your suggested `catch` code never runs, by the way. It isn't an error to have an empty result, and it wasn't the OP's problem).  As you point out, on the next user button press, the function is called again, this time with the parameter of `cards[card.length-1]`. What is the value of that expression for an empty cards array?

Comment: if(!data.docs.length) console.log('end of the row.'); — this is where I run another db query to get some other item instead. Because if I set my cards to an empty array, my user will see an empty screen, which might bring him to the state of mind where he might just divert from this thing entirely.

Comment: Okay.  I think what you're saying is, in that `if(!data.docs.length)` condition, imagine some other code that *won't* cause the problem that the OP has. I agree ;-)

Comment: I think that nether fixes increase the quality of code, nor do they intend to get work done instead of the author, but merely here to point out source of the confusion. I don’t at all find it a bad idea to apply imagination to improve yourself instead of taking a dump in public. In light of what you are saying, let me also bring it to your attention, that in imaginary case scenario, where we set cards to an empty array, display nothing to the user and, hey, hide a next button at that point: as the saying goes: it’s to late to drink borjomi when your kidneys are gone.

Comment: Do you mean "One way to fix is to conditionally render the button only if cards.length > 0."?  I agree again!